# How to get Cookie of Request Header after reponse in C#

Tags: c#, .net, window, .net-4.5, windows-10-universal

I want to get cookies "Request Header" not "Reponse Header" of links "https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/"
I have used WebRequest and HttpClient but when I did not see Cookie debug in it
Please help me write it in C # I find trying to find every possible way but I still have not found.

Comment: The client sets the cookie after receiving one from the server so you would already have it if you set it. You set cookies with a `CookieContainer` but again, you have to get one from the server first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **[System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)** for example, we can get cookies like following:

```
var myClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
myClientHandler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

var client = new HttpClient(myClientHandler);

var response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/");

var cookieCollection = myClientHandler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/"));

foreach (var cookie in cookieCollection.Cast<Cookie>())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(cookie);
}
```

`HttpClient` saves cookies that are sent by a server and automatically add them to subsequent requests to that URI within the same app container. So if we didn't modify cookies manually, the cookies in "Request Header" should be the same as what returned in previous reponse.